# Change margins for specific pages

Tags: margins

I want to change margins specifications for the first page of each chapter.

I know about geometry package to set up margin of the whole document. Is there a way to change that setting at the first page of each chapter, then return the default setting again?

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

Thanks

Comment: See `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` of the same package.